# ElasticSearch Grok Pattern issue for Custom Log String

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, logstash, logstash-grok

I am trying to create a complete GROK pattern on Elasticsearch for the following custom JSON based log:

```
------------------------DEBUG----------------------------
Date   : 2019-12-26 12:18:21,498 
METHOD NAME:   xyz
{
  "methodName": "SMS_POOL_IN",
  "Tran_Type": "Response",
  "URL": "xyz.abcL",
  "ApiResult": "Success",
  "Date": "2019/12/26 12:18:21",
  "ErrorCode": "00",
  "ErrorReason": "Success",
  "Msisdn": "9999999",
  "CNIC": "99999999",
  "RequestID": "1111",
  "SR_TranID": "2222",
  "Channel": "abc"
}
```

but when ever I parse this, i get only timestamp from the grok.

I am using grok debugger to test this. Whenever i use greedydata, i get only first json parameter, rest gets ignored, am i missing something here? how can i make a grok from these logs? Any helping hand would be appreciated

I have created below grok

```
%{GREEDYDATA.*}%{SPACE \s}%{GREEDYDATA.*}%{SPACE \s}%{GREEDYDATA.*}%{SPACE \s}%{GREEDYDATA.*}%{SPACE \s}%{GREEDYDATA.*}%{SPACE \s}%{GREEDYDATA.*}%{SPACE \s}%{GREEDYDATA.*}%{SPACE \s}%{GREEDYDATA.*}%{SPACE \s}%{GREEDYDATA.*}%{SPACE \s}%{GREEDYDATA.*}%{SPACE \s}%{GREEDYDATA.*}%{SPACE \s}%{GREEDYDATA.*}%{SPACE \s}%{GREEDYDATA.*}%{SPACE \s}%{GREEDYDATA.*}%{SPACE \s}%{GREEDYDATA.*}%{SPACE \s}%{GREEDYDATA.*}%{SPACE \s}%{GREEDYDATA.*}%{SPACE \s}%{GREEDYDATA.*}%{SPACE \s}%{GREEDYDATA.*}
```

and getting following result with this.

```
{
  "GREEDYDATA": [
    [
      "------------------------DEBUG----------------------------",
      "Date   : 2019-12-26 12:18:21,498 ",
      "METHOD NAME:   xyz",
      "{",
      ""methodName": "SMS_POOL_IN",",
      ""Tran_Type": "Response",",
      ""URL": "xyz.abcL",",
      ""ApiResult": "Success",",
      ""Date": "2019/12/26 12:18:21",",
      ""ErrorCode": "00",",
      ""ErrorReason": "Success",",
      ""Msisdn": "9999999",",
      ""CNIC": "99999999",",
      ""RequestID": "1111",",
      ""SR_TranID": "2222",",
      ""Channel": "abc"",
      "} ",
      "",
      ""
    ]
  ],
  "SPACE": [
    [
      "\n",
      "\n",
      "\n",
      "\n  ",
      "\n  ",
      "\n  ",
      "\n  ",
      "\n  ",
      "\n  ",
      "\n  ",
      "\n  ",
      "\n  ",
      "\n  ",
      "\n  ",
      "\n  ",
      "\n",
      "",
      ""
    ]
  ]
}
```

I need to show all these json tags segregated as i need them to populated in seperate tags in ELK

Comment: "*how can i make a grok from these logs?*". Please let us know what the  desired result of the grok pattern should look like! And also, please post what you have already implemented.

Comment: @apt-get_install_skill i have edited the question, I have shared complete details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created the grok myself, the only issue was with the syntax i was trying to build the grok. Below is the correct grok syntax to read above

```
%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:date_time}\s*%{GREEDYDATA:Method}\n%{GREEDYDATA:Bracket}\s*\"methodName\"\:\s\"%{DATA:methodName}\s*\"Tran_Type\"\:\s\"%{DATA:Tran_Type}\s*\"URL\"\:\s\"%{DATA:URL}\s*\"ApiResult\"\:\s\"%{DATA:ApiResult}\s*\"Date\"\:\s\"%{DATA:Date}\s*\"ErrorCode\"\:\s\"%{DATA:ErrorCode}\s*\"ErrorReason\"\:\s\"%{DATA:ErrorReason}\s*\"Msisdn\"\:\s\"%{DATA:Msisdn}\s*\"CNIC\"\:\s\"%{DATA:CNIC}\s*\"RequestID\"\:\s\"%{DATA:RequestID}\s*\"SR_TranID\"\:\s\"%{DATA:SR_TranID}\s*\"Channel\"\:\s\"%{DATA:Channel}\s
```

First i picked up time stamp, then i picked up everything which is outside my json string in GREEDYDATA, and then i segregated json tags with DATA keyword.

result for above is

```
{
  "date_time": [
    [
      "2019-12-26 12:18:21,498"
    ]
  ],
  "YEAR": [
    [
      "2019"
    ]
  ],
  "MONTHNUM": [
    [
      "12"
    ]
  ],
  "MONTHDAY": [
    [
      "26"
    ]
  ],
  "HOUR": [
    [
      "12",
      null
    ]
  ],
  "MINUTE": [
    [
      "18",
      null
    ]
  ],
  "SECOND": [
    [
      "21,498"
    ]
  ],
  "ISO8601_TIMEZONE": [
    [
      null
    ]
  ],
  "Method": [
    [
      "METHOD NAME:   xyz"
    ]
  ],
  "Bracket": [
    [
      "{"
    ]
  ],
  "methodName": [
    [
      "SMS_POOL_IN","
    ]
  ],
  "Tran_Type": [
    [
      "Response","
    ]
  ],
  "URL": [
    [
      "xyz.abcL","
    ]
  ],
  "ApiResult": [
    [
      "Success","
    ]
  ],
  "Date": [
    [
      "2019/12/26 12:18:21","
    ]
  ],
  "ErrorCode": [
    [
      "00","
    ]
  ],
  "ErrorReason": [
    [
      "Success","
    ]
  ],
  "Msisdn": [
    [
      "9999999","
    ]
  ],
  "CNIC": [
    [
      "99999999","
    ]
  ],
  "RequestID": [
    [
      "1111","
    ]
  ],
  "SR_TranID": [
    [
      "2222","
    ]
  ],
  "Channel": [
    [
      "abc""
    ]
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you wanted to separate out first 3 lines into 3 separate fields and rest of the JSON string object into another field.

I copied your input text from here so every line ended with `\n`. So this was my pattern match element.

Let me know if the `output` needed more parsing etc.

my pipeline configuration that has `grok` pattern to parse the input

```
input {                                                                                                                            
           http {

           }

   }

  filter {

          grok {
                  match  => { "message" => "(?<debug-string>[^\n]+)\n(?<date-string>[^\n]+)\n(?<method-name>[^\n]+)\n%{GREEDYDATA:RestOfIt}" }
          }
         mutate {
                 remove_field => ["headers", "host", "@timestamp", "@version"]
         }

  }

  output {
          stdout {

          }
}
```

**The OUTPUT**

{
         "**message**" => "------------------------DEBUG----------------------------\nDate   : 2019-12-26 12:18:21,498 \nMETHOD NAME:   xyz\n{\n  \"methodName\": \"SMS_POOL_IN\",\n  \"Tran_Type\": \"Response\",\n  \"URL\": \"xyz.abcL\",\n  \"ApiResult\": \"Success\",\n  \"Date\": \"2019/12/26 12:18:21\",\n  \"ErrorCode\": \"00\",\n  \"ErrorReason\": \"Success\",\n  \"Msisdn\": \"9999999\",\n  \"CNIC\": \"99999999\",\n  \"RequestID\": \"1111\",\n  \"SR_TranID\": \"2222\",\n  \"Channel\": \"abc\"\n} ",

"**date-string**" => "Date   : 2019-12-26 12:18:21,498 ",

"**method-name**" => "METHOD NAME:   xyz",

"**RestOfIt**" => "{\n  \"methodName\": \"SMS_POOL_IN\",\n  \"Tran_Type\": \"Response\",\n  \"URL\": \"xyz.abcL\",\n  \"ApiResult\": \"Success\",\n  \"Date\": \"2019/12/26 12:18:21\",\n  \"ErrorCode\": \"00\",\n  \"ErrorReason\": \"Success\",\n  \"Msisdn\": \"9999999\",\n  \"CNIC\": \"99999999\",\n  \"RequestID\": \"1111\",\n  \"SR_TranID\": \"2222\",\n  \"Channel\": \"abc\"\n} ",

"**debug-string**" => "------------------------DEBUG----------------------------"
}

Comment: I have posted the result in my answer which i was looking for :)